# Apply validation value according Yii in model

Tags: php, yii

I need to make a validation rule on the model when a value is received apply a rule and another value when applied another rule.

for example:

```
if($model->id = "1")
{
   return array(
       array('numero_documento', 'length'),             
   );
}

if($model->id = "2")
{
          return array(
       array('numero_documento', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
   );
}
```

This is an idea of what I want to do in the model rules

Comment: you need to write a custom validation for it.
you can refer this 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refactory the rules method like

```
public function rules() 
{
     $rules = array(//index of your habitual rules); 
     if ($this->id == 1) {
        $rules[] = array('numero_documento', 'length');
     } elseif ($this->id == 2) {
        $rules[] = array('numero_documento', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true);
     }
     return $rules
}
```

however this is a rare design of validation rules

Comment: Or maybe you can use scenarios, like
     return array(
        //habitual rules
         array('numero_documento', 'length', 'on' => 'lengthValidation'),  
         array('numero_documento', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true, 'on' => 'numericalValidation'),
     );

and in the model declaration set the scenario according of the case, but i insist your rules are very rare